# Why useState set don't work inside useEffect in react?How can i fix this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-development-server

So this is my problem:

```
import sanityClient from '@sanity/client';

export const client = sanityClient({
  projectId: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_SANITY_PROJECT_ID ,
  dataset: 'production',
  apiVersion: '2022-09-08',
  useCdn: true,
  token: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_SANITY_TOKEN,
  ignoreBrowserTokenWarning: true
});
```

for this project i use sanity client

```
import { useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import {client} from './client'

function App() {
 const [User, setUser] = useState()

 useEffect(()=>{
    const getUserData=()=>{
       const query = `*[_type == "user" && _id == 'John']`;
       client.fetch(query).then((data)=>{
       console.log(data[0]) //return data as expected
       setUser(data[0])
       console.log(User) //return undefined
     })
   }
    getUserData()
 },[])
```

Why when i reload the page setUser don't work inside useEffect and return undefined?

Comment: setUser changes the state and triggers a rerender.  User will not be set until after that rerender.  React is designed with a declarative style rather than the imperative you are assuming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will. not get data instantly
use new useEffect like this

```
import { useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import {client} from './client'

function App() {
 const [User, setUser] = useState()

 useEffect(()=>{
    const getUserData=()=>{
       const query = `*[_type == "user" && _id == 'John']`;
       client.fetch(query).then((data)=>{
       setUser(data[0])
     })
   }
    getUserData()
 },[])

 useEffect(()=>{
    if (User) {
       console.log(User)
    }
 },[User])
```

Answer (score 0):

You wont get any log, but your code is correct. It's because
`setState(updater[, callback])` 
**setState** tells its children and the component needs to be rerendered.
So you wont get immeditately the changed state value. If you console log **before** the `useState`, you'll see 
at first its showing undefined but after rerendering you'll get the updated state value.

Comment: Still not working, can you give me an example code please? I tried to display User in a h1 tag but i get an error in console that say: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined,i also tried to reload the page and i get the same error.